# How to fix Eclipse Luna Downlaod

Tags: eclipse, windows-8

![When I was trying to download and trying to run but it shows that error is windows 8.I need help or video link that will help me to solve this problem Thanks.][1]
I need help to download Eclipse latest version that was Luna and I tried to install but that error appears.So I need your guidance how to fix this error I have already jdk install and jre 7 also I have already in my Computer.

Error is Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:Program Files(*86)Java\jdk"

Comment: You probably have a 64 bit Eclipse with a 32 bit JDK - they must both be 32 bit or both 64 bit.

Comment: Sounds like a 32-bit Eclipse without a 32-bit Java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume OP had a typo and it's really `C:\Program Files (86)\Java\jdk`, which would mean there's a 32-bit JDK on a 64-bit Windows, and most likely a 64-bit Eclipse. Like +greg pointed to, get a 32-bit Eclipse. It's the least invasive solution.